# The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time

Tags: sql-server

I have large table (70 million records) which is also heavily indexed (5 indexes) and I need to merge with it around 100 000 records (several times in a row). So I do merge and some merges are ok and some return

> The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.

The merge has no transactions around it and is called (as a stored procedure) from entity framework (v 4.0) also without any transactions.

```
using (var b = new MyEntities())
{
    b.CommandTimeout = 36000;
    b.Merge_My_Stuff();
}
```

Also the server has 16 Gb of RAM (most of which is taken by sql server), the data in that table is 2.5 Gb and indexes are 7 Gb.
I've checked memory constraints and they are

```
max server memory (MB)  2147483647  2147483647  Maximum size of server memory (MB)
min server memory (MB)  0   16  Minimum size of server memory (MB)
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Also why on earth would sql server need so many locks to do a merge?

**Edit**
The merge statement is (execution plans I'll add later)

```
merge Target_table as target
using (select * from I_Tmp) as source
on target.A_ID = source.A_ID and
   target.B_ID = source.B_ID and
   isnull(target.C_ID, 0) = isnull(source.C_ID, 0)
when not matched by target then
    insert(A_ID, B_ID, C_ID, D, E)
    values(source.A_ID, source.B_ID, source.C_ID, D, E)
when matched then
    update
    set D= source.D,
        E= source.E;

delete from I_Tmp
```

Comment: Please add the actual merge statement and ideally the execution plan of it

Comment: Try doing multiple, smaller batches, rather than 100K at a time.

Comment: Looks like lock escalation is disabled. Why else would SQL Server take millions of locks? Check the table options and trace flags. SQL Server is perfectly capable of writing 70 millions rows in one statement. No trouble doing that at all.

Comment: @usr sys.tables says lock_escalation = 0, lock_escalation_desc = TABLE. Is that ok? One thing I also noticed is that each index has 'Alow row locks = true'. All of these are default.

Comment: Let's run an experiment. Apply `WITH(TABLOCKX)` to all tables involved in that statement. The error should be gone. This shows that the number of locks generated by this statement is the problem, as suspected by me.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx Go through the list of scenarios and requirements for lock escalation. Is there anything that would prevent it? For some reason it looks like the query is taking one lock per row of target. 100k locks are nothing. The error probably comes from trying to take 70m locks.

Comment: P.S. your use of `IsNull()` stops the optimiser using any indexes on these columns.

Comment: @usr with(tablockx) the error is gone, thank you. Gonna research that lock escalation thing later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a lock timeout error.  It's likely unrelated to server memory, and is instead caused by contention with other threads.

Here are a couple things which might help:

1. Ensure that an index exists with all of the merge conditions (A_ID, B_ID, C_ID) as keys (even better if your clustered index has these as its keys)
2. Reduce batch size significantly

If you are unable to reduce batch size, consider using the TABLOCK/TABLOCKX hint in your MERGE statement.  Due to the large batch size, SQL is likely escalating your locks to table locks anyway, which increases transaction time.  Going directly to table locks should mitigate timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on sql server 2016 after install of CU15.
Instance Properties > Advanced > Locks ... I found new feature in MAXDOP section.
Default was 50000, I was try to set on 0, but cant apply with click on OK.

Later: I found resolution:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
reconfigure;
exec sp_configure 'Locks', 0;
reconfigure;
```

Comment: certainly because some concurrent threads was doing something in the scope of the table...